# background image isn't loading properly

Tags: html, css

I tried to add a background image to the span but, for some reason, it doesn't seem to be properly loading. The jsfiddle is below.

P.S-I know its kinda straight "it doesn't works question" just got stuck for a while couldn't find a answer

http://jsfiddle.net/whnb3yf2/46/

```
<div class="learn">
<a>Learn More</a>
<span></span>
</div>

.learn 
 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
 background-color: transparent;
 border:2px solid #fff;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18pt;
 line-height:60px;
 overflow: hidden;
  }

 .learn a 
 {
 color: white;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   }
   .learn:hover {
   background-color: white;
   }

  .learn:hover a 
   {
   color: black;
   margin-left: -20px;
    }

   .learn span 
    {
    background:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-128.png) center;
    display: block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
     left: 110%;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

   .learn:hover span{
     left: 80%;
    }

   body {
    background-color: black;
      }
```

Comment: did you mean the .learn span class?

Comment: @Andrew are you referring to my answer?

Comment: @hopkins-matt indeed, but you got it first :)

Comment: @Andrew An explanation for your question: I referred to it as a rule because that's what it is. `.learn` is a class and `span` in that context is referring to a type element located within an element with the `learn` class. Those selectors combined with declarations make a rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `background-size: 9px 16px;` to your `.learn span` rule.

```css
.learn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height:60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.learn a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.learn:hover a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.learn span {
  background:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-128.png) center center;
  background-size: 9px 16px;
  display: block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 110%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover span{
  left: 80%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn">
  <a>Learn More</a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did come like a different picture when i didn't mention the background size ? . And Thank you

Comment: Because it was attempting to display the image at full size.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the background image for the button is too small. You can fix that by setting the background size equal to that of the button. For more information on the background-size attribute, check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```css
.learn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height:60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.learn a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.learn:hover a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.learn span {
  background:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-128.png) center center;
  background-size: 9px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 110%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover span{
  left: 80%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn">
  <a>Learn More</a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```